# How to compare one DataFrame with another one-row DataFrame and color or modify cells accordingly?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a `DataFrame`

```
data
```

and it's means

```
data.describe()['mean':'mean']
```

(didn't find better way to extract row of means)

I would like to display `data` so that it be visible, which values are larger than mean (and color it with red of attach some label, like "larger") and which values are smaller than mean (and color it with blues or label it with "smaller").

I understand, that coloring may depend on output technolory, so I use jupyter notebook and

```
from IPython.display import display
```

Coloring is not required. Replacing for strings with labels is ok.

**UPDATE**

I need values to contain in separate 1-row table, not calcuated on the fly.

**UPDATE 2**

Suppose I have 2 datasets

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1,5))
```

and would like to color `df1` according to `df2`?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1,5))
df1.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df2.loc[0, x.name], 'color: green', 'color: blue'))
```

[image]

**OLD answer:**

You can use [Pandas Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html):

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(x >= x.mean(), 'color: red', 'color: blue'))
```

Comment: What if values are contained in separate table, not calculated on the fly?

Comment: @Dims, what values do you mean? Could you make a simple example (sample data set)?

Comment: Thanks, but what goes for `x`? Row, column, cell or something else? I am receiving `Series lengths must match to compare`. See my update 2 please.

Comment: @Dims, `x` - is a current column. `.apply(lambda x: ...)` - will be applied to all columns - column-by-column. BTW - check updated answer

Comment: if this would be true, then we had the same style for each column

Comment: Another nice post MaxU + 1.  Thanks also for clipboard solution.

Comment: Using `x > df2.loc[0, x.name]` is pretty bizarre. Going over axis=1 you can just use  `x > df2.values[0]`

Comment: @TedPetrou, yes, but `.apply(..., axis=1)` is usually __much__ slower compared to `.apply(..., axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

For the updated question you can simple use

```
df1.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df2.values[0], 'color: red', 'color: blue'), axis=1)
```

First it would be good to create some sample data. Here we use numpy to do so and then take the mean in a much cleaner manner.

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
df.mean()
```

Output

```
0    0.543436
1    0.371999
2    0.473440
3    0.585303
4    0.370456
dtype: float64
```

You can then use `np.where` along with the `style` method to color the text appropriately

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(x < df.mean(), 'color: blue', 'color: red'), axis=1)
```

[image]